Horkheimer-Adorno and ethnology
I'm reading Horkheimer and Adorno'sDialectic of Enlightenment (1947) and in the first chapter the authors refer to mani.
Are there some references regarding the relations of H&A with ethnology: specifically with Durkheim and Mauss?
There is a reference to General theory of Magic in footnote 21.
